# Ubuntu Home folder opens hidden files

Tags: 14.10

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I must have done something to change how the Home folder opens, not sure what do.

When I open the Home folder it displays all files, even the hidden ones.  I have used Ctrl+H to hide the files and clicked on the View and unchecked Show Hidden Files but once I close and open the file again it shows the hidden files.  Not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2):

Quick solution: Open a terminal and run `gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences show-hidden-files false`

Slow solution:

1. Install dconf-tools via your favourite means (for example, running `sudo apt install dconf-tools` from the terminal)
2. Open a terminal and run `dconf-editor`
3. In the left hand panel, navigate to “org -> gnome -> nautilus -> preferences”
4. In the right hand panel, find the "show-hidden-files" option, and change the value to False

Answer (score 0):

First check your current setting in the terminal using:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.nautilus.preferences show-hidden-files
true
```

Then open `nautilus` (file manager) and select `Edit` then `Preferences`. On the screen that appears uncheck the "show hidden and backup files" option:

[image: nautilus hide system files.png]

Exit Nautilus and confirm the setting has changed using the command line:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.nautilus.preferences show-hidden-files
false
```