# Home directory displays hidden files too

Tags: home-directory, hidden-files

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I must have done something to change how the Home folder opens, not sure what do.

When I open the Home folder it displays all files, even the hidden ones. I have used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to hide the files and clicked on the View and unchecked Show Hidden files.

Moreover I have tried both the solution given at [Ubuntu Home folder opens hidden files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867658/ubuntu-home-folder-opens-hidden-files) but these are not working too.

Comment: Are you using the default file manager (Files, aka nautilus)?

Comment: The slow instructions you linked to, work for me. Do you have  dconf-editor? `sudo apt-get dconf-editor` if you do not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
Right click any file or directory, select "copy to". With the new window, that has appeared, is open use CTRL+H or right click the text area on right side of the it and select "hide".

Close filebrowser, reopen it and view home folder and see if hidden files are still visible.